# Why am i getting an "Error running query: Operand should contain 1 column(s)" error

Tags: sql

Apologies for the simple question as I'm a newbie in sql but i'm just trying to figure out why I'm getting this error this query?

```
SELECT (answer.user_survey_id, user_agent.browser, user_agent.browser_version, user_survey.user_id) 
FROM answer 
INNER JOIN user_survey on answer.user_survey_id = user_survey.id 
INNER JOIN user_agent on answer.user_agent_id = user_agent.id 
WHERE answer.user_survey_id = "18070"
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on SQL technology, but looks like you have the  parenthesis that you dont need, see query below.  Also I changed the double quotes to single quotes in your where (again depends on technology if this is correct syntax or not)

```
SELECT answer.user_survey_id, user_agent.browser, user_agent.browser_version, user_survey.user_id
FROM answer 
INNER JOIN user_survey on answer.user_survey_id = user_survey.id 
INNER JOIN user_agent on answer.user_agent_id = user_agent.id WHERE answer.user_survey_id = '18070'
```